# What is the name of this connector and where can I find it?

Tags: batteries, connector, light, remote-control, 18650

Any ideas on where I can locate this connector? It is from a bike light and connected directly to 18650 battery. 3mm x 2mm with 4 holes, but 2 wires from the battery. On the motherboard the connector is surface mounted (not accessible for photo), but looks like the housing has no separator for the connecting pins (so I am guessing not molex).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

That looks like a JST SFKR-02V-S

https://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eSFK.pdf

[image: sfk drawing]

The MKS-L crimper costs $1000+ but Digikey carries pre-crimped jumpers with a contact at each end for less than $1 each so you can cut one in half and splice onto it.